# Get the color of a pixel from camera intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am new with android studio and I have a question about camera.I have done the [Take photo](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics) tutorial and now I have a button that opens my camera app. I want to take the color of a pixel from the camera app without saving the picture. 
It is possible or I need to make camera API in order to take that color?

Any suggestion or tips about how I can make this project are welcomed.

Comment: (correct me if i am wrong) By using an intent you can open another app from you're current app. In my case I press a button that (by intent) opens the standard camera app. I was thinking that I can't take the color because the standard camera app can't make that. But maybe is a way of doing that so i don't need anymore to make another app that opens camera without intent. Or maybe it is more easily for my project to use camera without intent in order to take the color from a pixel. I just need to know what way should i go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android camera intent either saves an image file, or it is cancelled. You need camera API approach to catch pixels without creating files. You can use a library like fotoapparat to wraps the tricky API for easy usage.